# Using a single attribute as both a primary key and a foreign key in a subtype table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a supertype table (from ERD) called `Card` and this table has two subtypes: `Credit Card` and `Debit Card`. I have a `Primary Key` in my table `Card` named as `CardID`.

Will it be correct if I assign the `Primary Key` of `Card` as both the foreign key and primary key of `Credit Card` and `Debit Card`?

How do import the primary key of a supertype table to its subtypes (the code)? Do I simply do this?

```
CREATE TABLE [Credit Card] (
    CreditCardNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    CreditCardNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL Foreign Key REFERENCES Card(CardID)
)
```

Comment: and how is column CardID defined ? As a sidenote, its always better to name your primary key and foreign keys

Comment: You cant have 2 columns with the same name, what is it that you want to accomplish ?

Comment: I defined `CardID` as `CardID varchar(50) NOT NULL, ---other columns in the table---, CONSTRAINT PK_Card PRIMARY KEY (CardID)` in `CREATE TABLE Card` @GuidoG

Comment: Most of the time it's better a single table with a discriminator column CardType, for performance and simplicity reasons.

Comment: @JesúsLópez I haven't learnt what a discriminator column is. Is there a way to avoid that for now?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer the accepted answer by GuidoG shows you how to use the discriminator column. It's just a column that tells you which type of entity is stored in the row.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yeah, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this

```
create table dbo.[Credit Card] (
  CreditCardNumber varchar(50) not null,
  other columns ...

  constraint PK_CreditCardNumber primary key (CreditCardNumber),
  constraint FK_CreditCard_Card foreign key (CreditCardNumber) references Card(CardID)
)
```

This will only work if the column `CardID` in table `Card` has the same definition as the column `CreditCardNumber` in table `Credit Card`
Just from looking at the names this might not be the case ?

Most of the times it is better to use a discrimator field and just one table.
For example

```
create table dbo.Card (
   CardNumber varchar(50) not null,
   CardType char(1) not null check (CardType in ('C', 'D')),

   CreditCardColumn1 varchar(50) null,
   CreditCardColumn2 varchar(50) null,

   DebitCardColumn1 varchar(50) null,

   constraint PK_CardNumber primary key (CardNumber),
)
```

The check constraint will make sure only `C` or `D` can be stored in this colum.
Both columns for Credit Card and Debet Card have to be put into this table.
The query that you write should be different for each type, the table will always be the same

Now when you need all creditcards just do

```
select c.CardNumber,
       c.CardType,
       c.CreditCardColumn1,
       c.CreditCardColumn2
from   dbo.Card c
where  CardType = 'C'
```

and for all debitcards just do

```
select c.CardNumber,
       c.CardType,
       c.DebitCardColumn1
from   dbo.Card c
where  CardType = 'D'
```

Comment: What is the function of `dbo` in `dbo.[Credit Card]`?

Comment: It's the default schema

Comment: `dbo` is the schema name where you put your table in. `dbo` is the default, if you omit this it will be made in .dbo also

Comment: @GuidoG My `CreditCardNumber` and `CardID` are the same thing, though. It's like... I have different attributes for different kind of cards. I'm using subtypes `Credit Card` and `Debit Card` to fill in attributes that don't match between these two types of cards. I'm sorry if I worded my intention poorly >.< And the `CardID` does have the same definition of `CreditCardNumber` :-D Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: having 2 tables to store the information is only usefull when both entities have a small amount of the same columns, and a large amount of different columns. And also if one type is not used as much as the other.

Comment: Have you considered using just one table and a field to mark if its a credit card or a debit card ? It would be easier later when you start writing queries to access the data

Comment: @GuidoG I've read that, it's about the supertype table, subtype table and supertype-subtype table right? My lecturer has yet to mention this, but I'm just curious. I know that I should probably use the supertype table because there is only one different attribute in my ERD anyway, but if I do want to make it to the supertype-subtype table, is the answer you posted the way?

Comment: @GuidoG Unfortunately, again, I have yet to learn how to add a field to mark if something is A or B. I reckon it's using `CHECK`? Could you provide me with a link that provides beginner's examples, please :-)?

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of a discriminator column. Hope it will help

Comment: @GuidoG Shouldn't it be `dbo.Card` instead (as it stores info for both debit and credit)? Also, I'd like to add an extra attribute if CardType is C (e.g. credit limit) and another different extra attribute if the CardType is D. How do I do that?

Comment: The name if the table would indeed be better `Card` yes. I will edit my answer again please wait a minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174482/discussion-between-wealthy-player-and-guidog).

Answer (score 2):

See [Doc\SQL\T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
CREATE TABLE [Credit Card] (
    CreditCardNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Foreign Key (CreditCardNumber) REFERENCES Card(CardID)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the credit card table is considerably different in structure than the debit card one, I suppose it makes sense to do the keys the way you are describing. You have to balance for yourself whether this solution is better than to just have a card table with all fields of either credit or debit card.

The way you have written your query is like saying you have two different column with the same name, as GuidoG stated. You want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Credit Card] (
    CreditCardNumber varchar(50) NOT NULL Primary Key,
    ....(other cols)....,
    CONSTRAINT FK_CreditCard_Card Foreign Key (CreditCardNumber) REFERENCES Card(CardID)
)
```

I'd like to add that the nature of your wondering about the best solution may be closely related to "polymorphic associations", check a bit around for it.

In response to your comment: The only thing *not* correct from the things you are saying is the "but" word. It seems to have gotten into your mind that it is "strange" if a column is both PK and FK; it is not. They are two totally irrelevant things, and SQL server couldn't care less. The PK makes sure each row has a different value in this column. The FK makes sure the value must exist in the possible values of a column from another table. No conflicts at all; except a possible philosophical/design conflict, which of course only happens in YOUR mind (not the sql server's structure), and which my response (and many others') covered already.

Comment: I think that this is what I want. But how does SQL know what my Foreign Key value is?

Comment: indeed I forgot the fk column^^

Comment: I see. Is it correct of my understanding to say that both `CreditCardNumber` and `CardID` are the same thing, only different names (i.e. they have the same value)? And say I have a `CardID` in `Card` with the value A0001, and I input A0001 inside `CreditCardNumber` in `CreditCard`, SQL will think: the primary key of `CreditCard` is named `CreditCardNumber`, but it is actually the same thing as the primary key of `Card` as it is a REFERENCE to a Primary Key in `Card`, correct?

Comment: I am adding a reply to this comment in the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I've gotten it now. Also, I've found more clarity in "The FK makes sure that value must exist in the possible values of a column from another table". I've never known that, so now it totally makes sense to me. Have a great day! I wish I could pick two answers instead of one. Totally different approach.

Comment: The foreign key will also prevent deleting of rows that are referenced. That is the second advantage